# Eclipse removes drop mediator after send

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I tried to implement a validation with FAULT in it something like this

```
<on-fail>
               <makefault version="soap11">
                  <code xmlns:tns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" value="tns:Receiver"/>
                  <reason value="Invalid Request!!!"/>
                  <role/>
               </makefault>
               <log level="full"/>
               <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
               <header name="To" action="remove"/>
               <send/>
               <drop/>
            </on-fail>
```

therefore I added DROP after SEND what function just as I wanted (without DROP I just recived FAULT message but the process did not stop what resulted into invoking some End points with incorrect inputs)

Then I needed to check on something and I open the same sequence in Eclipse and discovered that DROP got removed.
I tried to drag and drop DROP but got an error message that the SEND mediator cannot be followed by another mediator.

why?

do you happen to know a better way how to implement SEND + DROP so there is not a risk that I lose this when I open it in Eclipse?

thx a lot!

Comment: Can you add what you need to happen after receiving the fault? It is hard to give a specific answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add a Drop Mediator after a Send. It is invalid to add any mediators after the Send mediator, since the message context will be dropped after the send. May be instead of a SEND mediator you can try adding a Respond Mediator. Your use case is not so clear.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Developer Studio, we cannot specify any mediator after SEND mediator/ RESPOND mediator/ DROP mediator. This is because, ideally mediation flow should not continue after those mediators.

For your case, can you try CALL mediator[1] instead of SEND mediator followed by DROP mediator as follows

```
    <on-fail>
           <makefault version="soap11">
              <code xmlns:tns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" value="tns:Receiver"/>
              <reason value="Invalid Request!!!"/>
              <role/>
           </makefault>
           <log level="full"/>
           <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
           <header name="To" action="remove"/>
           <call/>
           <drop/>
   </on-fail>
```

1. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Call+Mediator